# Is the product of metric spaces normal?

Tags: general-topology

The product of a countable collection of metric spaces is always metric. Is it true in general that the product space of any collection of metric spaces is always normal?

Answer (score 2):

It is a classic fact, due to A.H. Stone, that $\Bbb N^{\omega_1}$ is not a normal space in the product topology, for a proof online see [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/the-uncountable-product-of-the-countable-discrete-space-is-not-normal/).

So taking a non-compact metric space $X$ (products of *compact* metric spaces are always normal, as a compact Hausdorff space is, and we can apply Tychonoff's theorem) and looking at $X^I$ where $I$ is uncountable, we note that $X$ has a closed subspace $A$ that is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N$ (this follows from being a non-compact metric space) and so $X^I$ has a closed subset that is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N^{\omega_1}$ (as $\omega_1$ injects into $I$), and so cannot be normal as well (as normality is closed-hereditary).

So $\Bbb N^{\omega_1}$ is the simplest counterexample and it extends to a lot of other cases where we have enough copies of $\Bbb N$ into factors. I like $\Bbb R^{\omega_1}$ because it is even a separable topological vector space that is not normal. Of course all products of metric spaces will be Tychonoff (completely regular, or $T_{3\frac12}$) but as we saw, that's the best we can expect.

Comment: The same argument also shows that if the factors are compact but infinite, then the product is normal but not hereditarily so, which is a nice way to produce examples of not hereditarily normal spaces in my opinion. (no uncountable product is hereditarily normal, but this takes more work)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Indeed, every infinite Hausdorff space has a subspace homeomorphic to $\Bbb N$, so no uncountable product of infinite Hausdorff spaces is hereditarily normal is an easy consequence.

Comment: Right, and using $2^{\omega_1}\simeq (2^{\omega_1})^{\omega_1}$ plus the fact that $2^{\omega_1}$ has an infinite discrete subspace you can also drop the infiniteness condition and just get that any uncountable product of Hausdorff spaces is not hereditarily normal

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem, due to Arthur Harold Stone, which states that the product of uncountably many non-compact metric spaces is never normal. So, take, for instance, an uncountable product of copies of $\Bbb R$, endowed with its usual topology. It will not be normal.

Comment: It follows from the fact that $\Bbb N^{\omega_1}$ is not normal.